# Cannot add or update a child row

Tags: php, mysql, banco-de-dados

Boas, tenho estas tabelas com as seguintes estruturas:

**Atletas:**
  `id_atletas` 
  `id_identificacao` 
  `nome_completo`
  `licenca`

**Identificacao:**
  `id_identificacao`
  `nome_pretendido` 
  `data_nascimento`

O id_identificação está como FK na tabela Atletas e queria que ao registar o atleta o ID_identificação da tabela Identificação incrementasse na tabela Atletas.

Tenho o seguinte código:

```
$query_identificacao = "INSERT INTO identificacao (nome_pretendido, data_nascimento) VALUES ('$nome_pretendido', '$data_nascimento')";
$id = mysql_insert_id();

$query_atletas = "INSERT INTO atletas (nome_completo, licenca, id_identificacao) VALUES ('$nome_completo', '$licenca', '$id')";
$id = mysql_insert_id(); 

mysql_query($query_identificacao) or die(mysql_error());
mysql_query($query_atletas) or die(mysql_error());
```

Mas da-me o seguinte erro:

> Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`teste`.`atletas`, CONSTRAINT `atletas_ibfk_7` FOREIGN KEY (`id_identificacao`) REFERENCES `identificacao` (`id_identificacao`))

Comment: No primeiro `$id = mysql_insert_id();` é retornado um valor válido?

Answer (score 2):

Só depois que você executar a query (com `mysql_query()`) é que você vai poder pegar o id inserido (com `mysql_insert_id()`). Exemplo:

```
$query_identificacao = "INSERT INTO identificacao (nome_pretendido, data_nascimento) VALUES ('$nome_pretendido', '$data_nascimento')";
mysql_query($query_identificacao) or die(mysql_error());
$id_identificacao = mysql_insert_id();

$query_atletas = "INSERT INTO atletas (nome_completo, licenca, id_identificacao) VALUES ('$nome_completo', '$licenca', '$id_identificacao')";
mysql_query($query_atletas) or die(mysql_error());
$id_atleta = mysql_insert_id();
```